# Why am I receiving the error CS0119: 'DragDrop' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, drag-and-drop

Allow drop is set to true
I am receiving an invalid operation exception on the drag and drop line.
when add the dragdrop static variable to watch I get the CS0119 message

```
private void StackPanel_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {


        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            // Package the data.
            DataObject data = new DataObject();
            StackPanel parent = (StackPanel)sender;
            UIElementCollection children = parent.Children;

            data.SetData("Name", children[0]);
            data.SetData("Value", children[1]);


           * DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, data, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is `DragDrop` where it is defined

Comment: DragDrop is a static variable it comes from System.Windows.DragDrop